# Users have privilege to "Access Management" section in "Administration" without having System Administration access

Tags: 2013-sp1

Users have privilege to "Access Management" section in "Administration" tab when they are member of a specific Group in SDL Tridion - 2013 SP1. However, users are not System Administrator.

The issue is occurring in one specific environment only and working fine in other environments.

Risk: All the users who are member of this specific group are able to "Access Management" section in Administration tab.

Please let me know how to restrict non admin users from getting System Administration privileges.

Comment: can you **edit** your question and provide some more details on what the specifics of this group is that seems to be giving users Access Management?

Comment: What options are available in their Administration tab? For instance, if the group has Workflow Management rights in one or more Publications, they will be use the Workflow Management section of the Administration tab -- but nothing else.

Comment: Also, check the Privileges tab on the group itself -- maybe they have some privileges that they should have.

Comment: Sorry I've missed to post the workaround here which I used.
I've added an exception to deny the 'Permission Management Rights' on each publication. This has fixed the issue.

Comment: To Deny the specific group access to the 'Permission Management Rights' please do the below:
- Select the Properties of a publication and then select the 'Security' tab.
- At the bottom of the page select the 'Show Exceptions' check box.
- Then select the 'Show All' check box.
- Select the specific group in the bottom left box.
- Select the 'Permission Management' Rights in the bottom right box.
- Save and Close
- Repeat for each of the publications.